# Data Structure to store a Table values in python

Tags: python

[REFERENCE](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/32268735?key=c2b3c9ae22430807b69f080049d2e736)
What can be the most efficient way to store and retrieve this type of table.

| Product | Category | Original Price | Discount(%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Stationary | 1000 | 10 |
| Second | Clothing | 2000 | 5 |

```
stationary_items =[]
stationary_items.append({"Product" : "NOTEBOOK", "Category" : "STATIONARY", "Price" : 200, "Discount" : 20})
stationary_items.append({"Product" : "PENS", "Category" : "STATIONARY", "Price" : 300, "Discount" : 10})
stationary_items.append({"Product" : "MARKERS", "Category" : "STATIONARY", "Price" : 500, "Discount" : 5})


clothing_items = []
clothing_items.append({"Product" : "TSHIRT", "Category" : "CLOTHING", "Price" : 1000, "Discount" : 10})
clothing_items.append({"Product" : "JACKET", "Category" : "CLOTHING", "Price" : 2000, "Discount" : 5})
clothing_items.append({"Product" : "CAP", "Category" : "CLOTHING", "Price" : 500, "Discount" : 20})
```

I have to make queries later like **if product is notebook then do something**
edit : I cannot use 3rd party libraries,

Comment: The code is not legal, `list.append` can only have one parameter at a time. BTW, you may need to use `pandas`.

Comment: A hash table (dictionary in python) is good for this kind of data. (plus you can't append more than one parameter at a time)

Comment: fixed it thankyou, but how do i make queries do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `NamedTuple` since you have a fixed set of keys (table headers).

You can use [one-line factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

```py
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
```

or a [class-like definition with type-hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```py
class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int
```

Both of this approaches gives your a nice hints for defined attributes and allows you to not pay hashing costs.

If you have a list of such namedtuples, than you can filter it like
`[item for item in clothing_items if item.category == 'clothing' and product == 'tshirt']`,
it returns you a list of matching items.

You can describe a custom collection class, to store items hierarchically. smth like that (suppose that `Product` is namedtuple describing a table row):

```py
class ProductsByCategory:
    def __init__(self):
        self._products_by_category_map: dict[str, list[Product]] = defaultdict(list)
    
    def add(product: Product):
        self._products_by_category_map[product.category].append(product)

    def __getitem__(self, category) -> [Product]:
        return self._products_by_category_map[category]
```

Then list of products related to `'clothing'` category may be accessed like `products_by_category['clothing']`.

With this approach you can go further and make it "product by product name map by category map", also you can control in `add` method that there is only unique pairs of category and product name, so `product_by_name_by_category['clothing']['tshirt']` may return you exactly one Product instance, instead of list of Product instances, so you can access it's `.discount` field directly.

Keep in mind possibility of `KeyError` while accessing products.

Comment: yes nice answer. You also have dataclasses which can be equivalent to named tuples

Comment: Thankyou for answering, but is there any way to store it like a hierarchical fashion somewhat like json, so that i can query something like if category is clothing and product is tshirt then give me the discount or price,

Comment: I've update my answer with a pair of examples